# array on MIPS Assembly

Tags: arrays, assembly, registry, mips

I'm trying to write a mips function which return the position of the maximum value but I'm getting this exeption *(Error in /home/ams/Bureau/part2a line 21: Runtime exception at 0x00400028: address out of range 0x00000000)*

```
# MIPS assembly code

# $s0 = array base address, $s1 = i
# initialization code

main: lui  $s0, 0x23B8           # $s0 = 0x23B80000
     ori  $s0, $s0, 0xF000   # $s0 = 0x23B8F000
     addi $s1, $0, 0            # i = 0
     addi $t2, $0, 1000      # $t2 = 1000
     addi $t3, $0, 0            # $t3 =   max
     addi $s4, $0 , 0           #  $s4 = max indice

max:
loop: slt  $t0, $s1, $t2      # i < 1000?
     beq  $t0, $0, done      # if not then done
     sll $t0, $s1, 2              # $t0 = i * 4 
     add  $t0, $t0, $s0      # address of array[i]
     
     
     lw   $t1, 0($t0)        # $t1 = array[i] ERROR HERE 
     slt $t5, $t3, $t1      # max < array[i]
     beq $t5, $0,else   # if not then ense
     addi $t3,$t1, 0    # $t3 =: array[i]
     addi $s4, $s1,0    # $s4 =: i 
     #end
     
     else:   
     addi $s1, $s1, 1        # i = i + 1
     j    loop               # repeat

done: 
    addi  $v0, $s4, 0        # retval = max
    jr    $ra                # Return
```

any suggestion please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting $s1 to 0, and then trying to dereference it. Perhaps you meant $t0?

```
lw   $t1, 0($t0)
```

Comment: still having the same exeption but know Error in /home/ams/Bureau/part2a line 20: Runtime exception at 0x00400028: address out of range 0x23b8f000

Comment: Then your initialization is wrong, as it's the exact address you load $s0 with.

Comment: yes you are right something wrong with the initialization but i can't figure out what :/ any guess ?

Comment: How can you hope to find the maximum of an array if you don't know where it is?